# How to test PublishSubject

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2

I am trying to write a unit test for the example above. How can I mock and test PublishSubject return result

I have a PublishSubject

```
    fun loadData() {
        val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

        publishSubject.subscribe { 
            if(it) {
                view.onSuccess()
            } else {
                view.onError()
            }
        }

        useCase.loadDataFromServer(publishSubject)
    }

    @Test
    fun load_Data_From_Server_Success_Test() {             
        presenter.loadData()
        verify(view).onSuccess()
    }
```

But onSuccess method does not invoke(
How can I simulate onNext action using Mockito or PowerMockito?

Comment: Why don't you simply call `PublishSubject.onNext` when the time is right? Also are you even calling/testing the method `loadData`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you have a local `PublishSubject` in the `loadData()` method which is inaccessible from the outside so it can't be triggered in its current form.

You could replace it with `BehaviorSubject` that holds an initial value:

```
fun loadData() {
    val subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(true) // <----------------

    subject.subscribe { 
        if(it) {
            view.onSuccess()
        } else {
            view.onError()
        }
    }

    useCase.loadDataFromServer(subject)
}

@Test
fun load_Data_From_Server_Success_Test() {             
    presenter.loadData()
    verify(view).onSuccess()
}
```

or expose the subject in a field and call `onNext` on it from the test method

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create();

fun loadData() {

    subject.subscribe { 
        if(it) {
            view.onSuccess()
        } else {
            view.onError()
        }
    }

    useCase.loadDataFromServer(subject)
}

@Test
fun load_Data_From_Server_Success_Test() {             
    presenter.loadData()
    subject.onNext(true)    // <-----------------------------------------
    verify(view).onSuccess()
}
```

Comment: Class Presenter and class test it is separate classes. I cannot access the subject inside my test class

Comment: That's what I wrote as the main problem. Who is in control of these classes and can't you make it happen? I.e., have the subject as a parameter instead of a local variable?

Comment: I will try to change my logic. I'll delete the subject and use Observable instead.